# Django CSS not working when using block content

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to make a simple ordered list. Basically, I have a template that is a navigation bar that is at the top of every page in my web page. This is how the html/css looks on it.

```
{% block content %}
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  html {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ea0a8e;
    font-size: 18px;
  }

  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #121212;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 120rem;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .menu-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5rem;
    right: 2.5rem;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
  }

  nav {
    padding-top: 5rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  .logo {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    transform: translateX(-100rem);
    animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
    color: #ea0a8e;
  }

  .logo span {
    color: white;
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
  }

  nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    transform: translateX(100rem);
    animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
  }

  nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
  }

  nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: .5s;
  }

  nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
  }
  
  nav ul li:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  nav ul li:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: .5s;
  }

  nav ul li:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 3rem;
    position: relative;
  }

  nav ul li a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  nav ul li a::before,
  nav ul li a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: crimson;
    left: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: all .5s;
  }

  nav ul li a::before {
    top: 0;
    transform-origin: left;
  }

  nav ul li a::after {
    bottom: 0;
    transform-origin: right;
  }


  nav ul li a:hover::before,
  nav ul li a:hover::after {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  @keyframes slideIn {
    from {}

    to {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

    .menu-toggle {
      display: block;
    }

    nav {
      padding-top: 0;
      display: none;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
    }

    nav ul {
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    nav ul li {
      margin-top: 5rem;
    }

    nav ul li a {
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    .logo {
      font-size: 5rem;
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 11px;
    }

    body {
      scrollbar-width: thin;
      scrollbar-color: var(--thumbBG) var(--scrollbarBG);
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background: var(--scrollbarBG);
    }

    body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: var(--thumbBG);
      border-radius: 6px;
      border: 3px solid var(--scrollbarBG);
    }

  }
</style>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <h1 class="logo">GP Recon<span>ciliation</span></a></h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'stats' %}">Stats</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'addtransaction' %}">Add transaction</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'upload' %}">Docs</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'suggestion' %}">Suggestions</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
  {% endblock content %}
```

Now, I want to create a list using ul and il in a new page, but it is not working at all, unless I remove the block content. This is how the other HTML looks like.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
  .test ul li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>



<!-- Navigation bar -->
{% block content %}
{% include 'pythonApp/navbar.html' %}
{% endblock %}

<body>
  <ul>
    <li class="test">item1
      <ul>
        <li>subitem1</li>
        <li>subitem2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  
    <li class="test">item2</li>
    <li class="test">item3</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

My guess is that the CSS from the navbar template is overwriting whatever I write in the new file. Is there any way I can fix this? I've tried creating a class but failed. I'm not sure whether it is because I did it wrong (I'm a beginner with html) or because it's the wrong way of doing it.

**EDIT**

The `padding: 0` in the * element was messing everything up. I changed it to the nav ul element and it got fixed. I guess I should take more care of inheritance in later projects.

Comment: You probably want to use `extend` to get that  done.

Comment: @BATMAN that actually worked, but it messed up a bit with the design. I'll look deeper into extend, looks like it's better than include. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you make your navbar as your base html and extend your templates from that. It will make things a lot easier. That way, you won't have to repeatedly add your tags like javascript and bootstrap again and again.
They can all be in your base.html and since you keep extending that template. You get all those things ready to use.

Also, if your issue is solved please mark it as done. Have a great day!

Comment: @BATMAN Just to be sure of what you're saying. If I use extend, all of the css that I'm using in my base.html will be used in the places I'm adding ```extends``` to? The only problem I see with this is that I'm using different css for each of the urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are including the navbar template in your current template, it is bound to bring its css with itself and overwrite the css in your current template.

The best practice to work around this issue would be that you give class names to your navbar tags and use them in its css specifically for your navbar tags.